# AWS Instance Scheduler Lambda Function Update

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I needed to update the runtime of the lambda function that runs the Instance Scheduler solution from python 2.6(which is not supported anymore by AWS) to the latest python.
Now I'm not an expert in python(or in coding at all) and I don't know if it's possible to simply update the lambda function without re-installing the entire instance scheduler solution stack from CloudFormation.
I'm not sure if the python code itself was tweaked to match the infrastructure somehow(dynamodb, tags, etc...) or if it was left with all the default values when it was intalled.

I tried to update the lambda function by donwloading it locally into VSC and run 2to3 python update.
However it doesn't look like the function is working because when I put it in place of the old one and attached the old trigger with event bridge, the function appears to be running every 5 minutes but it won't shut down the required instances.
The log files in CloudWatch aren't showing if it generates any errors either, it just shows that it was executed and the time it run.
I assume the person that implemented it the first time used this but an older version: https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/instance-scheduler-on-aws/

So how can I make it work? Can I just download the python app from the github source and deploy it in lambda or it's worth re-deploying the entire CloudFormation stack?

Thanks